# Triple Integral by cylinder

Tags: multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

Calculating the volume of $E,$
where $E$ is bounded by $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$
and $x^2+y^2=2y.$

I've changed this to cylinder coordinate
; $\theta: 0-\pi , r : 0-2\sin(\theta), z : 0-\sqrt{4-r^2}$

then the gorgeous "wolfram alpha" gave the result
: $\frac {8\pi}{3} - \frac {32}{9}$

and it's right ans

I wanna know my prob. solving this

$\iint r \sqrt{4-r^2}\ dr\ d\theta$

$=\int 8(\frac {1-\cos^3\theta}{3})\ d\theta$

$=\frac {8\pi}{3}$ .....?! (Wrong)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. As you are a new user, it could be good to know this about the site. We make use of Latex here. This is done by enclosing math inside double dollar signs. A good site dealing with Latex for a beginner is https://www.google.se/search?q=codecogs&oq=codecogs&aqs=chrome..69i57.2179j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8. Another good one is http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html.

Comment: $(4-4\sin^2\theta)^{\frac 32}  = |\cos^3\theta|$  At the next step of the integration you need to break it up into two pieces $\int_0^{\frac \pi2} \frac 83 (1-\cos^3\theta) \ d\theta  + \int_{\frac \pi2}^{\pi} \frac 83 (1+\cos^3\theta) \ d\theta$

Comment: Thanks for reeditting by Latex and for solving the prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:  It appears that you think that the integral of $-\frac{8}{3} \cos^3 \theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$ is zero.  You might want to check that.

Comment: Thank you very much I got it yeah!